# DNN Upgrade Stalls 9.10.2 to 9.13

Tags: dotnetnuke, dnn9

I am trying to upgrade my DNN site from 9.10.2 to 9.13, which stalls checking security aspects.

I have removed all Telerik and RadEditor references (modules and references in web.config, siteurls.config). I only use a few modules, and these are fully updated.

The only error I can see is in the developer tools console:

ScriptResource.axd?d=NJmAwtEo3IoToslpzh_-JEPdID0Kiq42HuBP__DA4NqIX2Bim_r8WQ1nfAW4WeP43ZFWTE5zSLdUv5IcEsjc2ZAaK3onikCZAudXpWCzfA7rW26jPdhuhy7k5sfym4Gp01PgXw2&t=49337fe8:5
POST mydomain.com/install/upgradewizard.aspx/GetSecurityTab 500 (Internal Server Error)

I have tried several times and am at a loss for what to do next. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked the InstallerLog in /portals/_default/logs?

Comment: There is nothing.  As it gets stuck on checking security aspects, the upgrader may not have got far enough to start the upgrade process.

Comment: Have you tried upgrading without the wizard directly at /install/install.aspx?mode=upgrade?  Another suggestion is to verify that your application pool has full write privileges to the the site root and all subfolders as this can frequently stall upgrades.